# Replace a context-param element with a Servlet 3.0 annotation

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, annotations

Given: a Java EE 5 web app that has a web.xml that has a snippet like

```
<context-param>
    <description>c</description>
    <param-name>a</param-name>
    <param-value>b</param-value>
</context-param>
```

What would I need to do to move that context-param specification into an annotation based strategy.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do it using annotations. The Servlet Context parameters are container-wide. Therefore I don't even know where you should put them (it doesn't make much sense to put them next to any particular Servlet). A `ServletContextInitializer` would seem to be the most adequate, but I don't think it's possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find all `javax.servlet` annotations in the [`javax.servlet.annotation`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/4.0/apidocs/javax/servlet/annotation/package-summary.html) package summary:

> - [`@HandlesTypes`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/4.0/apidocs/javax/servlet/annotation/HandlesTypes.html)    This annotation is used to declare the class types that a `ServletContainerInitializer` can handle.
> - [`@HttpConstraint`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/4.0/apidocs/javax/servlet/annotation/HttpConstraint.html)    This annotation is used within the `ServletSecurity` annotation to represent the security constraints to be applied to all HTTP protocol methods for which a corresponding `HttpMethodConstraint` element does NOT occur within the `ServletSecurity` annotation.
> - [`@HttpMethodConstraint`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/4.0/apidocs/javax/servlet/annotation/HttpMethodConstraint.html)  This annotation is used within the `ServletSecurity` annotation to represent security constraints on specific HTTP protocol messages.
> - [`@MultipartConfig`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/4.0/apidocs/javax/servlet/annotation/MultipartConfig.html)   Annotation that may be specified on a `Servlet` class, indicating that instances of the `Servlet` expect requests that conform to the multipart/form-data MIME type.
> - [`@ServletSecurity`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/4.0/apidocs/javax/servlet/annotation/ServletSecurity.html)   This annotation is used on a `Servlet` implementation class to specify security constraints to be enforced by a Servlet container on HTTP protocol messages.
> - [`@WebFilter`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/4.0/apidocs/javax/servlet/annotation/WebFilter.html)     Annotation used to declare a servlet `Filter`.
> - [`@WebInitParam`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/4.0/apidocs/javax/servlet/annotation/WebInitParam.html)  This annotation is used on a `Servlet` or `Filter` implementation class to specify an initialization parameter.
> - [`@WebListener`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/4.0/apidocs/javax/servlet/annotation/WebListener.html)   This annotation is used to declare a WebListener.
> - [`@WebServlet`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/4.0/apidocs/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html)   Annotation used to declare a servlet.

You see, there's nothing like a `@WebContextParam`. Which makes also less or more sense; on what kind of class would/could you set it?

Some Servlet based frameworks which rely on context parameters, such as JSF, also allows for setting some of them by JNDI. You might want to look into that instead. Or if it concerns homegrown code, then I'd look if `@WebInitParam` isn't a more feasible option for you.

Comment: I'd think something like `@WebContextParam` would be useful on a servlet as a way of injecting a context parameter into multiple artifacts (contrasted with a `@WebInitParam` for a single servlet/filter).

Comment: I am going to accept this answer.  It is an answer to what I asked... but not what I really wanted to ask.  I am going to open a new question to ask 'what I wanted to ask'...

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Tomcat, you can use the Parameter tag in `context.xml`, and it will work identical as a context-param put in `web.xml`.
So you can use `@WebInitParam` to catch a context variable.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html#Context_Parameters

Comment: Not entirely sure if this answers the question. I think the question might be about how to define the paramater in an annotation strategy, not necessarily access it. (but I could be wrong, so not down voting)

Answer (score 1):

Well I think we just can't hardcode **context-param** using  **"Annotation"** because there is a logical reason behind this : i am sure you guys knows annotations is always hardcoded in the Servlet and **Servlet** never loaded by the **container** in the memory for serving the client request until its **first request is made by client (read Servlet Life Cycle )**.

So what happen if we want to get the values out of      **"context-param"** , which is hard-coded using  Annotation in some other Servlet ? And the Servlet  **wrapped** with **context-param** annotation is still not loaded in the memory thus we can't get the **object for context** :)

I think now you guys can easily guess why we can't use Annotation in case of **context-param** because we need to hardcode that Annotation with any specific servlet and we can't do that .......

Answer (score 1):

One can specify the servlet content listener met data by using @WebServletContextListener. For instance,

```
 @WebServletContextListener 

public class TestServletContextListener implements javax.servlet.ServletContextListener { 
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) { 

    } 

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) { 
        .... 
    } 
}
```