# Java web: how to set a value that accessible all user sessions?

Tags: servlets

I am doing a web site with Spring MVC.

I am hoping to build a feature for the admin. As an admin, I would like set a value, which is accessible to all user sessions.

As you know, I can set a value in session, but it is only available to me. I am hoping to set a value accessible to all others in the same JVM.

What is the Java web feature for me to achieve my goal?

I already implemented a database-based feature which affects the users across all servers in a cluster. Now I would like to have a non-database per-JVM solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the attributes of the [ServletContext](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) which is the context of the web application.

In this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621580/how-to-get-the-servlet-context-from-servletrequest-in-servlet-2-5)  you can find a reference of how to access and use it.

Comment: fmodos, thanks for the info!!! I recall this servlet feature now. I will read that and come back later to select yours as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `web.xml` in your application then you can do something like this

```
<web-app>  
 ......  

  <context-param>  
    <param-name>paramName</param-name>  
    <param-value>paramValue</param-value>  
  </context-param>  
 ......  
</web-app>
```

If you are using `annotations` then, you can find all javax.servlet annotations in the `javax.servlet.annotation` [package summary](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/package-summary.html).

[refer this link for detailed info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970051/replace-a-context-param-element-with-a-servlet-3-0-annotation)

Comment: Hi Prince Mani Gupta, thanks for your information. Good to know the approach you mentioned. Cheers!