# How to disable syncid in Vaadin

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

Hi I am trying to disable sync id in vaadin or set it to -1 how can i achieve this.

i have tried following things but it didn't worked.

```
@WebServlet(initParams = { @WebInitParam(name = "syncIdCheck", value = "false") }) // UI class

// this is in web.xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>syncId</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: What is that `syncId`?

Comment: It looks like the functionality you are going after should be available https://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/14084

Answer (score 2):

The correct web.xml context parameter is following:

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>syncIdCheck</param-name>
   <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Unfortunately there is *no* `@WebContextParam`in Servlet 3.0: [Replace a context-param element with a Servlet 3.0 annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970051/replace-a-context-param-element-with-a-servlet-3-0-annotation)